# Attempt to write a readonly database Django/Apache2/OperationalError

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

I am working on a Django app and have deployed it to a Ubuntu Server via AWS. Everything that doesn't require a database insert works fine. But when I try to log in (everytime if someone logs in I am saving the 'last login') an OperationalError appears: Attempt to write a readonly.

I already changed the owner of the database and tried also with `chmod 666` and `chmod 777` but it still doesn't work.

Did someone had the same issue and has solved it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Stupid mistake -> I didn't set the permissions on the parent folder of database.